# Box and line in R plot Legend

Tags: r, plot

I've done a plot, and have one small problem which drive me crazy with the legend part

I can't find a way to center the box in the legend.

```
x=seq(-4,4,length=200)
 y=dnorm(x,mean=0.816783035,sd=0.862916258)
 plot(x,y,type="l",lwd=2,col="red" , xlim=c(-4, 4) ,  ylab="probabilitiy", xlab="")


 #Shaded Area TBR!
 c= -0.211653725


 x=seq(-4,4,length=200)
 y=dnorm(x,mean=-0.393475584,sd=0.895660247)
 lines(x,y,type="l",lwd=2,col="blue")


 legend("topright", legend = c('TBR', 'TBF', 'Criterion', 'Hit'), 
               bty = "n",
               col = c("green", "blue", "red",NA),
               lty = c(1,1,1,NA),
               density=c(0,0,0,10),
               fill = c("green", "blue", "red","red"),
               border = c(NA,NA,NA,"red"),
               )
 abline(v= c)

 x1 = seq(c,4, length = 200)
 y1 = dnorm(x1,mean=0.816783035,sd=0.862916258)

polygon(c(c,x1) ,c(0, y1),density= 3, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the "x.intersp" parameter you will need to play with I think.
Try:

```
x=seq(-4,4,length=200)
 y=dnorm(x,mean=0.816783035,sd=0.862916258)
 plot(x,y,type="l",lwd=2,col="red" , xlim=c(-4, 4) ,  ylab="probabilitiy", xlab="")


 #Shaded Area TBR!
 c= -0.211653725


 x=seq(-4,4,length=200)
 y=dnorm(x,mean=-0.393475584,sd=0.895660247)
 lines(x,y,type="l",lwd=2,col="blue")


 legend("topright", legend = c('TBR', 'TBF', 'Criterion', 'Hit'), 
               bty = "n",
               col = c("green", "blue", "red",NA),
               lty = c(1,1,1,NA),
               density=c(0,0,0,10),
               fill = c("green", "blue", "red","red"),
               border = c(NA,NA,NA,"red"), 
               x.intersp=c(2,2,2,0.5)
               )
 abline(v= c)

 x1 = seq(c,4, length = 200)
 y1 = dnorm(x1,mean=0.816783035,sd=0.862916258)

polygon(c(c,x1) ,c(0, y1),density= 3, col="red")
```

[image]

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Looks right, though `c(1,1,1,-0.5)` might be a better fit as it doesn't seem to alter the spacing of the other parts of the legend.